# Should all players be able to roll skill checks together?

Tags: dnd-5e, skills

Recently started DMing and, during the game, they captured a Goblin and attempted to pry information from him.

My question is, is *every player* allowed to roll intimidation/persuasion in an attempt to individually coerce the Goblin? On that note, if a PC fails their intimidation can they also roll persuasion after (although if I allow it I'd do so with disadvantage as they just attempted to coerce the creature in the polar opposite way).

Comment: You might want to look at [this](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/57142/15469) question or [this](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/56017/15469) question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From the rules:

> ## Working Together
>
> Sometimes two or more characters team up to attempt a task. ***The character who’s leading the effort—or the one with the highest ability modifier—can make an ability check with advantage, reflecting the help provided by the other characters.*** In combat, this requires the Help action (see chapter 9). A character can only provide help if the task is one that he or she could attempt alone. For example, trying to open a lock requires proficiency with thieves’ tools, so a character who lacks that proficiency can’t help another character in that task. Moreover, a character can help only when two or more individuals working together would actually be productive. Some tasks, such as threading a needle, are no easier with help.
> (PHB5e p.175)

This means the character who is interrogating the goblin with the highest charisma modifier gets to make a check with advantage. No one else makes a check.

If the players switch up their tactics, then a new check is performed. It's up to you, as a DM, to determine when a new check can be performed.

Comment: I'd stress that it's up to you (DM) to determine if and when *any* check if performed--not just a re-check. The interrogator makes a check *if the GM asks for one.* "Working Together" doesn't supersede the general notion that GMs always are the one to ask for a check, not players. (Though we players might gently suggest that our situation might warrant a check.)

Comment: Players should be rewarded for ingenuity. If they can come up with a plausible cause (they took some effort to justify it), I'd be more inclined to include the effects of the rule. They might claim to be playing good-cop/bad-cop, or perhaps some special technique, or ... whatever. Going out of the way to encourage player teamwork fosters more teamwork, which is the main attraction of the game.